# Changing firebase data according to query

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code

```
Query mSeenRef = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageRecieverId).child(MessageSenderId).orderByChild("From").equalTo(MessageRecieverId);
```

This is the query and I want to change another child if this query is true... Like similar to adding value event listener and fetching this above querys data... just that instead of fetching i want to change data but I cant use setValue method inside value event listener so what should I do?

I also have UIDS inside MessageRecieverId and inside that is From

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query mSeenRef = db.child("Messages").child(MessageRecieverId).child(MessageSenderId).orderByChild("From").equalTo(MessageRecieverId);
mSeenRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
 @Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
  if(dataSnapshot.exist()) {
     for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
          String keyId=ds.getKey();
         DatabaseReference ref= db.child("Messages").child(MessageRecieverId).child(MessageSenderId).child(keyId);
         Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
             childUpdates.put("Seen", true);
             ref.updateChildren(childUpdates);
        }
      }
    }
@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
  }
};
```

This will check if the query exists in the database using `dataSnapshot.exists()`, then if this query exists, you will be able to change the value of a child. You need to use the method `updateChildren()` to update only one attribute.

Check here for more information:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields

Comment: Look to my edited question... how do i change the values of seen to true inside the UIDS... like i want to go inside the Push generated IDS and change if the query is true

Comment: do you have the nested ids?

Comment: DatabaseReference user_message_key;
        user_message_key = mDatabaseReference.child("Messages").child(MessageSenderId).child(MessageRecieverId);
        message_push_id = user_message_key.push().getKey();

Comment: its message_push_id but when i use that it just creates a new push id and creates a child inside it and sets its value to true but doesn't change the existing ones

Comment: check the answer, you access both the messageRecieverId and the messageSenderId then loop inside the senderid and get the directid. Then you will be able to update only "Seen" to true using updateChildren

Comment: So if the query is true the above code is going to change all the UIDs data?

Comment: it will only change "Seen" to true

Comment: My problem got solved... Thats what i meant... thanks a ton